# Element not changing position when updating the style top and left

Tags: javascript

This code below should change the position of the element but fails to do so.

```
//variables
var p1 = document.getElementById("player");
var px = 10;
var py = 10;

//@variables

//functions

function start() {
    setInterval(update, 100);
}

function update() {
    p1.style.left = (px + "px");
    p1.style.top = (py + "px");
    px = px + 10;
    py = py + 10;
}

//@functions

//start
start();
//@start`
```

my html is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> jumpy </title>

    <style type="text/css">
        #player {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: white;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
        #body {
            background-color: black;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body id="body">
    <script src="jumpy.js"> </script>
    <div id="player"> </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

> Even though the position is absolute it still does not work.
>   I have seen the answer at the bottom but it did not fix my problem.

Comment: Make sure player position is not static

Comment: set position to absolute

Comment: Is p1 absolutely/relatively positioned? Because the `left` and `top` properties only work when that's the case.

Comment: It is absolutely positioned

Comment: Your script is executed before the player is created. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your script is run *before* your element is created. As a result `document.getElementById("player");` returns nothing (the element is not loaded yet).

Move the script tag at the end of your body, or wrap your code in

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  // Your code.
});
```

Appart from this, your code works fine (except that [requestAnimationFrame should be used to create animation with js, not setInterval](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/animating-with-javascript-from-setinterval-to-requestanimationframe/)). If it does not, the problem is somewhere else.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){

  //variables
  var p1 = document.getElementById("player");
  var px = 10;
  var py = 10;

  //@variables

  //functions

  function start() {
    setInterval(update, 100);
  }

  function update() {
    p1.style.left = (px + "px");
    p1.style.top = (py + "px");
    px = px + 10;
    py = py + 10;
  }

  //@functions

  //start
  start();
  //@start`

});
```

```css
#player {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="player"></div>
```

Comment: *"except that requestAnimationFrame should be used to create animation with js, not setInterval"*, that's not entirely true. People also very often misuse `requestAnimationFrame` with having no `setInterval/setTimeout` in animations with logical code and games in JavaScript.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek In what cases would you use a `setInterval` to create an animation?

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` should **only** be called when you wish to update the screen via repaint. It's not to replace timers used for updating the screen, it's not a replacement for code lodic execution.

Comment: I agree that there is examples where it does not make sense (e.g. to create asynchronicity). However when it comes to animations (such as property animation like it is the case here), I don't see any examples where `setInterval/setTimeout`, that are not optimized for such operations, are more appropriate.